# Comparing 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I have 2 dataframes that contain 3 account indictors per account number. The account numbers are like for like in the column labelled "account". I am trying to modify dataframe 2 so it matches dataframe 1 in terms of having the same NaN values for each column.

**Dataframe 1:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1234567890,1,np.nan,'G'],
                    [7854567890,np.nan,100,np.nan],
                    [7854567899,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                    [7854567893,np.nan,100,np.nan],
                    [7854567893,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],      
                    [9632587415,np.nan,np.nan,'B']],
columns = ['account','ind_1','ind_2','ind_3'])
df
```

Output:

```
account         ind_1   ind_2   ind_3
0   1234567890  1.0     NaN     G
1   7854567890  NaN     100.0   NaN
2   7854567899  NaN     NaN     NaN
3   7854567893  NaN     100.0   NaN
4   7854567893  NaN     NaN     NaN
5   9632587415  NaN     NaN     B
```

**Dataframe 2:**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1234567890,5,np.nan,'GG'],
                    [7854567890,1,106,np.nan],
                    [7854567899,np.nan,100,'N'],
                    [7854567893,np.nan,100,np.nan],
                    [7854567893,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],      
                    [9632587415,3,np.nan,'B']],
columns = ['account','ind_1','ind_2','ind_3'])
df2
```

Output:

```
account         ind_1   ind_2   ind_3
0   1234567890  5.0     NaN     GG
1   7854567890  1.0     106.0   NaN
2   7854567899  NaN     100.0   N
3   7854567893  NaN     100.0   NaN
4   7854567893  NaN     NaN     NaN
5   9632587415  3.0     NaN     B
```

**Problem:**
I need to change dataframe 2 so that it is matching the same NaN values in dataframe 1.

For example: Column **ind_1** has values in index 0, 1 and 5 in df2, whereas in df1 it only has values in index 0. I need to replace the values in index 1 and 5 in df2 with NaNs to match the same number of Nans in df1. Same logic to applied to the other 2 columns.

**Expected outcome:**

```
account         ind_1   ind_2   ind_3
0   1234567890  5.0     NaN     GG
1   7854567890  NaN     106.0   NaN
2   7854567899  NaN     NaN     NaN
3   7854567893  NaN     100.0   NaN
4   7854567893  NaN     NaN     NaN
5   9632587415  NaN     NaN     B
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance
Alan

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`df2[~df.isna()]`

`df.isna()` check where df has nan value and create a mask
then slice df2 with the mask.

Answer (score 1):

You return a DataFrame with `True`  values where there are `NaN` values in your first dataframe using `df.isna()`. You can use this as a Boolean mask to set the correct cells to `NaN` in your second DataFrame:

```py
df2[df.isna()] = None
```

Be careful: I assume that you also need to take care that these NaNs will be associated with rows with the same value for `account`. This solution does not ensure that this will happen, i.e. it will assume that the values in `account` column are exactly int he same order in both dataframes.